# Streaming an API proxy in Vapor

Tags: swift, reverse-proxy, openai-api, vapor

I'm trying to make a proxy for the openAI chat api in Vapor, so that my iOS app won't need to know the api key. The thing that makes this a bit tricky is that I want to use streaming: `stream=true`. So I want to call this proxy from my iOS app, and it calls the openAI api with the key, and should stream the result back to my app (Server-Sent Events) as if I had called open AI directly.

I'm new to Vapor, so I don't really know what I' doing, but this is what I have so far:

```
app.post("chat") { req -> EventLoopFuture<ClientResponse>  in
        let targetAPIKey = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TARGET_API_KEY"] ?? ""
        let targetAPIURL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"

        var headers = HTTPHeaders()
        headers.add(name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer \(targetAPIKey)")
        headers.add(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/json")
        headers.add(name: "Accept", value: "text/event-stream")
        
        // Forward the received request body
        let requestBody: ChatQuery
        
        do {
            requestBody = try req.content.decode(ChatQuery.self)
        } catch {
            return req.eventLoop.makeFailedFuture(Abort(.unprocessableEntity))
        }

        return req.client.post(URI(stringLiteral:targetAPIURL), headers: headers) { downstreamReq in
            try? downstreamReq.content.encode(requestBody)
        }
    }
```

This more or less works. But it seems to take a lot longer to start streaming in the iOS app than if I called the api directly. And when it does start streaming, it streams super fast. It seems like  it doesn't start streaming to the app until the stream from openAI is complete. This significantly degrades the experience for the user. How can I make it stream to the app directly, as soon as it the stream from open AI starts?